# C++ CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer

Tags: c++

Here is my function that is supposed to find the first encountered process with the given name and returns a handle to it. however in the process i require to allocate some data on the heap which throws an error when i try to delete.

```
HANDLE GetProcessHandleByName(CHAR procName[])
{
    DWORD pProcessIds[1024];
    DWORD pBytesReturned;
    ::EnumProcesses(pProcessIds, sizeof(pProcessIds), &pBytesReturned);
    int noOfProcs = pBytesReturned / sizeof(DWORD);
    if (noOfProcs)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfProcs; i++)
        {
            HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                PROCESS_VM_READ,
                FALSE, pProcessIds[i]);
            if (!hProcess) continue;
            HMODULE hMod;
            DWORD cbNeeded;
            CHAR strBuffer[MAX_PATH];
            if (::EnumProcessModules(hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod), &cbNeeded))
            {
                auto length = ::GetModuleBaseName(hProcess, hMod, strBuffer, sizeof(strBuffer) / sizeof(CHAR));
                CHAR *str = new CHAR[length];
                ::strcpy(str, strBuffer);
                if (::strcmp(str, procName) == 0)
                {
                    delete[] str; //can't delete -> Exception CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.
                    return hProcess;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My *guess*? That you forgot that strings have an extra character in them (the terminator character `'\0'`), and you don't allocate space for that extra character.

Comment: Also, why use the temporary buffer `str`, when the string already is in `strBuffer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to allocate, copy, and delete it. Also, it causes memory leak if `::strcmp(str, procName) != 0`.

Try this:

```
            if (::EnumProcessModules(hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod), &cbNeeded))
            {
                auto length = ::GetModuleBaseName(hProcess, hMod, strBuffer, sizeof(strBuffer) / sizeof(CHAR));
                if (::strcmp(strBuffer, procName) == 0)
                {
                    return hProcess;
                }
            }
```